# Cosmos database throws 404 exceptions when using container.GetItemQueryIterator and iterator.ReadNextAsync

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

While using `container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>()` and `iterator.ReadNextAsync()` in V3 of the cosmos C# library.
I got the following error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : 

Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404);
Substatus: 0;
ActivityId: 8cf9bc78-59e7-44c0-aff2-63683694251d; Reason: (2022-04-20T23:02:51.9719128Z: GetTargetPartitionKeyRanges(collectionResourceId:6HlyAK3Jgts=, providedRanges: [,175630D7ECDD581BB95A8C894445F59F)
failed due to stale cache ...
```

This error happened very rarely.
What's the reason behind such an error?

Rest of the error message:

```
 ActivityId: 8cf9bc78-59e7-44c0-aff2-63683694251d, Windows/10.0.14393 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.19.3); at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosQueryClientCore.GetTargetPartitionKeyRangesAsync(String resourceLink, String collectionResourceId, List`1 providedRanges, Boolean forceRefresh, ITrace trace) at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosQueryClientCore.GetTargetPartitionKeyRangeByFeedRangeAsync(String resourceLink, String collectionResourceId, PartitionKeyDefinition partitionKeyDefinition, FeedRangeInternal feedRangeInternal, Boolean forceRefresh, ITrace trace) at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Pagination.NetworkAttachedDocumentContainer.MonadicGetChildRangeAsync(FeedRangeInternal feedRange, ITrace trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- Cosmos Diagnostics ---{"name":"Typed FeedIterator ReadNextAsync","id":"75a0278a-ac3d-471c-9f0a-5150eb3722b8","caller info":{"member":"OperationHelperWithRootTraceAsync","file":"ClientContextCore.cs","line":219},"start time":"11:02:51:531","duration in milliseconds":453.2367,"data":{"Client Configuration":{"Client Created Time Utc":"2022-04-15T05:02:15.9534005Z","NumberOfClientsCreated":2,"User Agent":"cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.20.1|3.19.3|2|X64|Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393|.NET Core 3.1.11|N|","ConnectionConfig":{"gw":"(cps:50, urto:10, p:False, httpf: False)","rntbd":"(cto: 5, icto: -1, mrpc: 30, mcpe: 65535, erd: False, pr: ReuseUnicastPort)","other":"(ed:False, be:False)"},"ConsistencyConfig":"(consistency: NotSet, prgns:[])"}},"children":[{"name":"Create Query Pipeline","id":"3c8033ae-43ad-4c76-b3fe-19ed38fae66f","caller info":{"member":"TryCreateCoreContextAsync","file":"CosmosQueryExecutionContextFactory.cs","line":85},"start time":"11:02:51:531","duration in milliseconds":0.3749,"children":[{"name":"Get Container Properties","id":"c95bbe7c-13d5-480f-b1a0-3e47c668d4e0","caller info":{"member":"GetCachedContainerPropertiesAsync","file":"ClientContextCore.cs","line":366},"start time":"11:02:51:531","duration in milliseconds":0.0073,"children":[{"name":"Get Collection Cache","id":"08d6d99a-2869-4665-b330-d71de293063b","caller info":{"member":"GetCollectionCacheAsync","file":"DocumentClient.cs","line":546},"start time":"11:02:51:531","duration in milliseconds":0.0007}]},{"name":"Service Interop Query Plan","id":"b9623e4b-3fa5-41cb-aa1f-5dedbab36c54","caller info":{"member":"GetQueryPlanWithServiceInteropAsync","file":"QueryPlanRetriever.cs","line":58},"start time":"11:02:51:531","duration in milliseconds":0.3343},{"name":"Get Partition Key Ranges","id":"98e8525e-5048-45a8-b8fe-54bb83166026","caller info":{"member":"GetTargetPartitionKeyRangesAsync","file":"CosmosQueryClientCore.cs","line":242},"start time":"11:02:51:531","duration in milliseconds":0.0154,"children":[{"name":"Try Get Overlapping Ranges","id":"1adba283-edbb-4674-ac5f-c35dd18096e1","caller info":{"member":"TryGetOverlappingRangesAsync","file":"PartitionKeyRangeCache.cs","line":53},"start time":"11:02:51:531","duration in milliseconds":0.0076}]}]},{"name":"MoveNextAsync","id":"ec767535-2117-44c0-9f06-431f75798ab3","caller info":{"member":"MoveNextAsync","file":"CrossPartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator.cs","line":113},"start time":"11:02:51:531","duration in milliseconds":441.7519,"children":[{"name":"Prefetching","id":"9bbb9f3c-d3a1-4ae8-aacb-cd1aac4beb37","caller info":{"member":"PrefetchInParallelAsync","file":"ParallelPrefetch.cs","line":31},"start time":"11:02:51:531","duration in milliseconds":0.0005},{"name":"[,175630D7ECDD581BB95A8C894445F59F) move next","id":"69e7cccf-0ba5-4928-a3c2-d34679ee51c7","caller info":{"member":"MoveNextAsync","file":"PartitionRangePageAsyncEnumerator.cs","line":49},"start time":"11:02:51:531","duration in milliseconds":296.7431,"children":[{"name":"Prefetch","id":"7d4ac0ff-3ad9-47--TRUNCATED--
```

Comment: Have you gone through the 404 guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-not-found? Which SDK version are you using? What is the full CosmosException details (.ToString()) ?

Comment: I have gone through the guide. And I am pretty sure that none of the scenarios match my situation. I have added the cosmosException. It is truncated, however. But I was not able to reproduce the error consistently, therefore unable to obtain the full exception details.

Comment: Does your application by any chance have any logic that might Delete Containers or Databases? That would probably be one of the reasons for this 404.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not have any logic to delete container or database. We have a lot of data in the container, so it would be noticeable if the container is deleted. This is also the only select query that had this error, all subsequent ones have succeeded.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I ran into the same issue and I do have a recreate container logic in there (delete+create). I still don't understand why though - after recreating the container I'm getting a new handler for it `_bulkClient.GetDatabase(databaseName).GetContainer(containerName)`